# How to find sum of digits inside InputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I already have the solution of this task, this code passed the tests. But I don't understand it.

And I `don't have` other part of the code, only this method. I should complete it and pass the tests.

Code of the tests I don't have too.

The solution:

```
public static int getSum(InputStream is)  {
    int sum = 0;
    try {
        int digit = is.read();
        while (digit != -1) {
            sum += digit;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

For example, if InputStream contains 1,2,10 then sum would be 13.

But how the program find 13 If `is.read()` method return byte representation of inputed digits instead of the certain digits?

It should be sum of 49 + 50 + (what is byte representation of 10? ) = more then 13

Comment: Depends on what your stream contains for sure.

Comment: Wrap a `DataInputStream` around input stream and use `readInt` to read integers from it directly.

Comment: @JohannesH. that makes the assumption that someone wrote integers to the stream in two’s complement and big endian.

Comment: @Boris If that's not the case, the presented solution wouldn't work either.

Comment: @JohannesH. The current solution reads a single byte at a time - it makes no assumptions about wider types. Using a `DataInput` would read 4 bytes at a time and make assumptions.

Comment: you mean the above solution is correct and can pass all the test cases?

Comment: _Depends on what your stream contains for sure._ - It is my question. I have no idea and haven't seen such way before. I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Are you solving this from a code challenge? If so, post the challenge here or its link.

Comment: @yelliver Yes, code passed the tests

Comment: What does the stream contain? Provide a specification for the binary format of the data written and we can help with a solution for reading it.

Comment: So it simply reads the stream every 8 bits, not every single digit as you thought, it is binary, not decimal

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have no more information. Only example of input and output, that I gave in the topic

Comment: @yelliver How can I create such stream myown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers that are read are present in the input stream in the same binary format Java uses (twos complement, big endian), reading them into an int will work as expected.

However, as only a single byte is read into the 4byte java int,  a solution will only work with numbers that happen to have all but the last 8 bit set to zero in 32 bit twos complement representation - that's positive numbers from 0 to 127.

Comment: Only a single unsigned byte would be read. If someone wrote something wider it would not work. The `int` is rather misleading.

Comment: Could you give some example how I can pass digits in binary format into the InputStream?

Comment: Agreed. But the code IS working as far as we know, so the stream contents HAVE to be that.

Comment: @AlexanderTulanov define the binary format.

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov for example by passing them to `OutputStream.write()`.

Comment: My point is that it’s not currently reading ints, it’s reading unsigned bytes. The relevance of the binary format of wider Java primitive types is dubious.

Comment: Ok I understood your point now. This would imply however that it's impossible for the solution to work as expected in more than just a few edge cases where all bits but the last byte of the numbers being sent are zero.

Comment: Yup, totally agree. If they are just sending numbers `[0,255]` it will work fine. They’d have to, as you note, use `OutputStream.write` if using Java.

Comment: @JohannesH. _OutputStream.write()_ - what do you mean? output stream hasn't method write that returns binary stream

Comment: @BorisTheSpider I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No, they send also two digit number, for example the number 10

Comment: 10 is within the range of one byte in two's complement. One digit is not equal to one byte, unless you send digit as ASCII characters.

Comment: @JohannesH. Ok, I got it, but I still have no idea how to create such stream by myown. Do you have? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Just create an outputStream and send numbers using its `write` method.

Comment: @JohannesH. Ok. `OutputStream o = System.out; o.write(50); InputStream is = ?;`
And how to pass 50 to input stream then?

Comment: You have to create your own output stream, not use System.out. You then have to connect the output stream to an input stream. `PipedOutputStream` and `PipedInputStream` might help.

Comment: @JohannesH. Ok, thank you man for help, but I think it's too hard for this task. Because this task is for beginners, it is not some pro challenge

Comment: Well the task doesn't require you to create such stream yourself, does it?

Comment: @JohannesH. I've marked this topic as solved in gratitude for the help. I think maybe they wanted to show students a work with InputStream on such example, but It's very strange

Comment: @JohannesH. Yes, I don't need to, but I think It's very unusual and tried to figure out this example

Comment: I agree that without specifying the stream contents, that task is a bit strange, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
byte[] arr = {1,2,10};
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
```

this method can be used for cr

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).